# HIP4081A power-up problem

Tags: pwm, h-bridge

I'm using the [HIP4081A](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/hip4081a-datasheet) in a h-bridge motor drive to drive PMDC motors. The design is working fine when running on 12V but now when I have added a buck/boost converter [TPS55165-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TPS55165-Q1) so I can run on either 12 or 24V I run into problems. The problem is that the fuse (70A) is sometimes blown directly when switching power on. I assume the problem is that both upper and lower side FET is conducting in the H-bridge.

[image: H-bridge diagram]

On [Renesas knowledge database](https://en-support.renesas.com/knowledgeBase/9370450) I found information that the supply voltage (12V) and the power for logic circuitry must come up at the same time to avoid unreliable startup condition.

To make sure that 12V power rises at the same time as 3.3V I have connected a diode from 3.3V to 12V. See picture. This however did not help. Fuse is blown and sometimes also the FETs.

[image]

Then I found a "common information" [TB321](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/oth/tb321-hip4080-and-hip4081-high-frequency-h-bridge-drivers?language=en) document from Renesas  which describes how the disable pin can be pulled high during start up and then taken low when power is up.

[image]

In the document is says that disable pin must be toggled from low to high after power is applied which can be done by the circuit shown above. My question is now, does anyone else had this same problem? How did you solve it? My problem is that I do not have any spare pins on the processor to pull the Enable signal high. (Since there is a document describing the power-up I guess this is a common problem.)

Comment: I have now tested the circuit that Renesas suggested (see picture above) where disable pin is pulled high by pull upp resistors and a transistor pulls the Disable signal low after power is up. Initial tests shows that this works fine. No shoot through happened so far.

Comment: ...but there is one sentence in the TB321 document that concerns me. It is this one:
"It is critical that ALI and BLI be held low prior to DIS reaching its threshold level of 1.7V while VDD/VCC is ramping up, so that shoot through is avoided". 
In my design ALI and BLI is not held low. (AHI and BHI are tied to VCC). If ALI or BLI is low the high side FETs will conduct if DIS=0. I understand that it is good to hold inputs low before power is up but since AHI/BHI is tied to VCC the PWM output will be high if disable pin is not low. It feels unsafe to set pwm high and rely on the disable pin.